# LLN and rates in terms of Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers, stieltjes-integral

I am learning about Stieltjes integrals. Written in terms of a Stieltjes, the law of large numbers, $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)\to E(X)$ as $n\to\infty$, looks like:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF_n(x)\to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF(x)
$$
or
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)d(F_n-F)(x)\to 0
$$
I am wondering 1. Can this be proven just using standard Stieltjes integral material and perhaps the additional fact about the uniform convergence  $F_n-F\to 0$? 2. Can you actually get the usual order of an IID average, $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)- Ef(X)=O(n^{-1/2})$ just using Stieltjes theory and the fact that $F_n-F$ is uniformly $O(n^{-1/2})$? I did not specify the mode of convergence for the LLN above since I don't know how much can be proven from this route.

Comment: I gather you are assuming $(X_n)$ is an i.i.d sequence, right? Rates of convergence of in this setting follows from the CLT. The Lebesgue integral (or rather Stieltjes-Lebesgue integral) provides the framework for rigorous justifications of convergence in a general setting. The $F_n$ in your posting is the *empirical distribution*: $F_n(x)=\frac1n\sum^n_{k=1}\mathbb{1}(X_k\leq x)$.

Comment: I suspect you need a finite second moment to get that rate of convergence

Comment: @Henry: of course!

Comment: @Henry I ageee and that confuses me even more. I have no idea how existence of a 2nd moment works its way into how the empirical CDF "looks" when it converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to 1)

We know that $\sup_x |F_n(x) - F(x)| \to 0$ by Glivenko–Cantelli theorem. Suppose that we "forgot" about the fact that $F_n$ corresponds to a sample from i.i.d. So lets condiser a sequence of c.d.f. $F_n(x)$ and $F(x)$. We know, that  $\sup_x |F_n(x) - F(x)| \to 0$. Does it follow that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF_n(x)\to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF(x)
$?

No. Suppose that $f(x) = x$ and $F_n$ corresponds to $n \cdot Bern(1/n)$, so $F_n = 1$ if $x \ge n$, $F_n = 0$ if $x < 0$ and $F_n= 1-\frac{1}n$ otherwise. Hence $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF_n(x) = \mathbf{E} ( nBern(1/n) ) = n\cdot \frac1n = 1$. Put $F(x) = 1$ if $x \ge 0$ and $F(x) = 0$ otherwise. $F(x)$ is a c.d.f. of constant $0$. Hence $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF(x) = \mathbf{E} 0 = 0$ and $\sup_x |F_n(x) - F(x)| \to 0$. Q.e.d.

Answer to 2)
We know that $\sqrt{n }\sup_x |F_n(x) - F(x)| \overset{d}{\to} \xi \sim \sup_t W_0(F(t))$ (see "Convergence of probability measures", Billingsley). Suppose that we "forgot" about the fact that $F_n$ corresponds to a sample from i.i.d. So lets condiser a sequence of c.d.f. $F_n(x)$ and $F(x)$. We know, that  $\sqrt{n }\sup_x |F_n(x) - F(x)| \overset{d}{\to} \xi$. Does it follow that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF_n(x) - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF(x) = O(n^{-\frac12})?$

No. Consider the previous counterexample. We have $\sqrt{n}\sup_x |F_n(x) - F(x)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and hence $\sup_x |F_n(x) - F(x)| = O(\frac1{\sqrt{n}})$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF_n(x) - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dF(x) = 1 \ne O(n^{-\frac12})?$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. Do you have any idea what the missing ingredient is, that makes the uniform convergence $F_n\to F$ different when $F_n$ is an IID sample? I wonder how it is expressed, without using probability language.

Comment: @kara890 This is "convolution structure" of $F_n$. I mean that $F_n(x)$ correspond to the sum of independent r.v.-s $\frac1n I_{X_i \le x}$. If we "forgot" about this structure we will get a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually from what I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679297/riemann-stieltjes-integral-and-uniformly-convergence) it seems the integral converges with probability 1. So it must be the interchange of the integral and the expectation that is causing the problem. This makes me wonder if it isn't the convolution structure but maybe something simpler, because doens't the example you give resemble many counterexamples to L1/a.s. convergence?

Comment: @kara890 Yes, my counterexample is a standard one. We proved that "everything is good if we have convolution structure" and "not everything is good if we don't have convolution structure". Everything is done. I suppose that now your new question is smth.like that: "Suppose that $g_n \to 0$, under which conditions on $f$ and $g_n$ we have $\int f(x) dg_n \to 0$". If it's true then it's a new question, because in the original question we had probability (and LLN). So you may ask another question if you want. Remark: I changed my answer a bit.